# Spring boot admin console Client

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

The spring boot admin console displays only two options in details. How to make sure all other details are displayed like environment,JMX,logging,etc

[Image of display button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN8ug.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Boot 2.0 you need to explicitly expose the actuator endpoint via setting `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` property